# On tensorflow on sagemaker receiving error as input must be a vector, got shape: [1,2]

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-hub

I have built a tensorflow model on Sagemaker. The model uses universal sentence encoder

```
import json
class MixEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

serialize_data = json.dumps({'input1': np.array(("Hello","World")) } , cls = MixEncoder  )
print(serialize_data)

response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,ContentType='application/json' ,Body=serialize_data)--
```

This line throws an error

> ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with message "{ "error": "input must be a vector, got shape: [1,2]\n\t
>
> The model expects only one tensor as input . It is defined as 
>   input_model_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None], name="tensor_input_model_1").

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Sagemaker, but this looks like a common mistake of trying to pass a sentence as a vector of words, and universal sentence encoder is supposed to take full sentences. Additionally it appears that Sagemaker is batching results because the example code passes an array of shape (2,) but the error was about (1, 2).

Try this:

```
json.dumps({'input1': np.array("Hello World")}, cls=MixEncoder)
```